# IPTABLES how to port forwarding out from 21 to 2100

Tags: iptables

I have a script that publishes files via FTP on another server, but the script only allows you to use port 21. On the destination server the only FTP port is 2100.

Is possible use IPTABLES on source server, to forward output connections on port 21 to 2100?

With this the script running on source server will try FTP on port 21, and IPTABLES forward this to port 2100 and the destination server will accept.

If is possible, can this rule only work with specific destination IP ?

Thank.

Comment: 21 is the standard port for FTP. If possible you should fix the destination FTP server so that it listens on the correct port.

Answer (score 0):

You must work with nat redirects

Example:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is theoretically possible to do it with iptables, I would not recommend doing it. This will probably generate more trouble than it will resolve.

My suggestion, in order of preferences would be:

1. If you can, get rid of ftp. It's an old and insecure protocol, which would be advantageously replaced by sftp (usually using port 22/tcp), or at least, ftps (ftp with ssl).
2. Use standard port on ftp server. There is rarely a good reason to change the default port of a service, unless the same server hosts multiple ftp server instances.
3. Modify the script to connect to port 2100 on this particular server. Most ftp client allows you to specify the destination port.
4. If none of the above are possible, you can use iptables DNAT command like this one (replace 1.2.3.4 with the IP of the FTP server):

   iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4:2100

Please note that the FTP Passive mode uses a reverse connection on port 22/tcp, which may certainly not work with just this iptables rule.